# Qunit test not recognizing defined object

Tags: qunit

I have a JS method I'm looking to test:

```
doMediation: function() {
    var state,
        that = this,
        mediation_rule = "asdf";

    Mediation.getRules(mediation_rule, function () {
        [blah blah]
    });

},
```

My Mediation object is defined *above* this method in my class. This is my qunit test:

```
test('doMediation: testing mediation', 1, function(){
    var proto = $.extend({}, My.prototype, {

    Mediation: {
        getRules: function(rule, cb){}
    }

    proto.doMediation();
});
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error:

```
Died on test #1: Cannot call method 'getRules' of undefined - {}
```

Yet, it is defined right there in the test. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out that previously, Mediation was defined as such: var Mediation = AnotherClass.Mediation. In the qunit test, I had to actually define AnotherClass.Mediation = {} instead of Mediation{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Turns out that previously, Mediation was defined as such: var Mediation = AnotherClass.Mediation. In the qunit test, I had to actually define AnotherClass.Mediation = {} instead of Mediation{}